# Didn't redirect to the default subdirectory action after login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The main directory that I use is 'DK Shop' and the SubDirectory in which I log in is 'Dk Shop Admin Panel'.
I am login into a subdirectory (Dk Shop Admin Panel) and redirecting to the default action (Index) in the same directory after login but it returns a 404 not found page from the main directory (DK Shop).
I hosted the Main Directory 'DK Shop' with a subdirectory (Dk Shop Admin Panel)  on IIS.

When login with credentials, first check whether the credentials are correct, and then Valid-user. After that after validating the security answer, create a custom authentication after entering the correct answer and then redirecting to the default action in the same subdirectory. But every time it returns the 'Page not found' page from its main directory.

Here my code for login,

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                this.ClearFormAuthontication();   
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = "")
        {
            try
            {
                //var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
                //var captchaReponse = this.ValidateCaptcha(response);

                
                //if (captchaReponse.Item1)
                if (true)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        if (this.LockUser(model.UserName, false) > 3)
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message = "Current user is locked!";
                            return View(model);
                        }

                        var user =  this._db.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(u => u.Username == model.UserName && SymmetricCryptor.Decrypt(u.Password) == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            this.LockUser(model.UserName, true);
                            Session["UserId"] = user.UserId;
                            model.UserID = user.UserId;
                            return View("ValidateSecurityAnswer", model);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message = "Incorrect username or password";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = this.GetAllModelError();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "The captcha is missing or wrong !.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MSError.Trace(ex);
                ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            
            return View(model);
        }
```

Here ValidateSecurityAnswer Code,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ValidateSecurityAnswer(LoginModel model)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateSecurityAnswer(LoginModel model, FormCollection form)
{

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int UserId = Session["UserId"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]) : 0;

            if (this._dbMngr.GetAnswer(UserId, form["txtAnswer"].ToString()))
            {
                User user = this._db.Users.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(use => use.Username.Equals(model.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && SymmetricCryptor.Decrypt(use.Password) == model.Password);

                var roles = user.Roles.Select(m => m.RoleName).ToArray();

                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel()
                {
                    UserId = user.UserId,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    roles = roles,
                };

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);

                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                UserId,
                user.Username,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                model.RememberMe,
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializeModel));

                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                //HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                //Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

                HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

                return RedirectToAction("index", "home"); // It exist in subdirectory project.
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Please enter valid answer";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = this.GetAllModelError();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MSError.Trace(ex);
        ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
    }

    return View();
}
```